# Association rules for continuous features

Tags: continuous-data, association-rules

I need to detect rules in a data set that contains real-valued features. A simplified example of my samples, defined by features a, b, and c, and having class 0 or 1, might look like this:

> 2.34, 1, 5.46 => 0
>
> 1.23, 0, 7.81 => 1

For this data set, I am interested in detecting rules like:

```
a > 1 and a<3 and b==1 => class=0
```

I have checked out association rule algorithms in Weka and then searched online, and they do what I want, but they all seem to need binary features. 
My question: is there an algorithm that can do what I want, or do I need to hack my own on the basis of existing association rule algorithms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like a decision tree algorithm (such as rpart in R) will do what you need.  Most decision trees will find rules similar to the one you outlined above.

Comment: Thanks! I got so focused on association rules that I forgot completely about decision trees.

Comment: 6 years later. Another guy, another user case but the same misfocusing. Just wanted to thank very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize and discretize the feature ranges. If you have a training dataset with scores in continuous space (e.g. BM25 retrieval scores), it can be normalized and split into multiple categories such that [0.25-0.50], [0.51-075], [0.76-1.00]. Now the minimum support and confidence can be decided by the specific distribution.