# What models can be used to prove causality?

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, model, research-design

Right now I am looking into analyzing the factors of crime in an economics paper. I currently have a multiple OLS regression set up that is pretty standard:

Y = B0 + B1(Variable) + B2(Variable) + B3(Variable) + ... + u (error term)

Here is a small sample of my dataset:

[image: A subset of my data]

However, this model seems very weak in terms of proving causality, or even telling us if there is a significant relationship.

Thus, my question is how can one prove causality with a time series dataset? I have looked into doing a Fixed Effects model, but (as I understand it) this only will control for variables that do not change over time, thus not helping much. I also looked into a Pooled OLS model, but this seems to only work when we have multiple entities observed over time, not just one. I have also looked into VectorAutoregression (VAR), but this seems mainly reserved for forecasting, not proving statistical relationships. In addition to this, I looked at Granger Causality but I believe that this also suffers from being too simple and not really providing anything of use.

What model would be the best to be applied here?

[image: DAG of this paper]

Comment: It’s not possible to draw causal relationships from observational studies.

Comment: @utobi That isn't true.  Its hard, I'll give you that, but there is an very large body of research which intends to draw causal inferences from observational data.

Comment: @DemetriPananos yes I am aware of it: causal inference that pays  a high price in terms of a lot of unverifiable assumptions.

Comment: @utobi "prove" is hard, draw causal conclusions is very much possible and verified (!) by running experiments concurrently.  Ie observational models and practitioners who have the right tools to test as many causal assumptions as possible / method to estimate causal graphs and non linear functions are proof that you can draw (better than random) conclusions from observational data that is not just "giving up" to solve a real world data problem. Eg medical treatments, advertising campaign design, ...

Answer (score 2):

> However, this model seems very weak in terms of proving causality

You can't just put data into a model and have causality.  There is a host of theory and assumptions about the process and intervention which must come prior to data in order to estimate a causal effect.

And even so, it might be the case that your model and theory are wrong in some important way, so *proving* causality is not really something that is on the table, and certainly not something you get for free from software.

So let's start here.  What are you modelling, what are you assumptions, and do you have a DAG?

Comment: I'm modeling the relationship between the velocity of money (m2v_means) and violent crime rates (viol_crime). I understand causality is extremely hard to prove, which is why I've done my best to research causes of crime, and include them as control regressors (unrate_mean, avg_temp, fam_gini, and tfr). The way I understand it, if I can control for *every* cause of crime then we can determine causality. Obviously, an impossible task but the goal is to get as close as possible, correct? My main assumption is that M2V precedes violent crime, and I do not have a DAG.

Comment: @shrey_shankar You should start with a DAG.  Adjusting for *every* possible cause (even if such a thing could be possible) is typically a bad idea since you could unknowingly induce a correlation between the exposure and target variable due to M bias.  McElreath (pejoratively) refers to such approaches as "causal salad".  You really need to think about your problem, confounders, and how they relate. Start with a DAG

Comment: I added a DAG to the OP. The way I understand OLS, the effects between variables don't compromise the efficacy of the model. This very well might be wrong, but to my understanding if (using the DAG for example) Poverty Rate and Unemployment Rate are correlated, this shouldn't compromise our model. Is this incorrect? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @shrey_shankar Your DAG would seem to imply that your exposure is independent of all other predictors and you can simply do a regression of violent crimes onto the exposure.  Now, I'm not a social scientist, but this seems incredibly implausible. SES does not appear in this DAG and yet I would bet that SES is both associated with velocity of money and violent crime.  If you believe this dag as written, perform your regression.  But the DAG is suspect, even from a non-expert perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [association analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), it produces plausible causal dependences based on your data. Typical example of usage is a shopping basket and relationships between items (e.g., if a customer buys milk, a customer buys bread). Usually, it is used on binary or categorical data, yours are continuous. You might find some ways how to use it, such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/340128/370163).

I recall that this method tends to produce quite flooded output, which you need to filter by looking at the support and the confidence values. Thus, you might want to read something about it before blindly applying to your data.

Good luck.